# How to update my view without freezing my app?

Tags: python, multithreading, pyqt5, qtableview

I was updating my tableView every minute (when my model is updating) without any problem and any freeze.

But now my update function is taking much more time than before because of specific extracts and so when I update my view it freezes until my update function is terminated.

How can I launch my update in another thread in order to avoid the freeze of my view ?

I tried to launch my timer within a thread_update but the freeze remains

```
class TicketGUI(QAbstractTableModel):
    def __init__(self, user_id, mdp, profile):
        QAbstractTableModel.__init__(self)
        self.EM = Extract(user_id, mdp) #Extract manager
        self.tickets = Tickets()
        self.tickets.load(self.EM, True) Load tickets from extract
        data = self.tickets.toDataframe()
        self._data = data

        # Update my table view each 60 seconds
        timer = QtCore.QTimer(self, timeout=self.on_timeout)
        thread_update = Thread(target=timer.start(60 * 1000))
        thread_update.start()

    def rowCount(self, parent=None):
        return self._data.shape[0]

    def columnCount(self, parent=None):
        return self._data.shape[1]

    def data(self, index, role=Qt.DisplayRole):
        [...]

    def headerData(self, col, orientation, role=Qt.DisplayRole):
        [...]

    def update(self, data):
        self.beginResetModel()
        self._data = data
        self.endResetModel()

    def on_timeout(self):
        self.tickets.load(self.EM)  #Load tickets from extract (THIS TAKES TIME)
        data = self.tickets.toDataframe()
        self.update(data)
```

Comment: thread needs function's name without `()` and arguments - like in `QTimer`. For arguments there is separated parameter -  `args=` - and it has to be tuple even if you have only one argument - `Thread( target=timer.start, args=(60*1000, ) )`

Comment: your current code starts timer in main thread and its result assigns to `target=`. Like `result = timer.start(60 * 1000)` `thread_update = Thread(target=result)`

Comment: Hi furas, thanks for your answer but it is still freezing
It looks like my on_timeout function does not properly run on another thread (different from the main one)

Comment: maybe do it in different order - create `Thread` inside `QTimer`  instead of creating `QTimer` inside `Thread`. It will create new thread every 60seconds (instead of using one thread) but maybe it will work better.

Comment: Thanks Furas but it does not actually work.
Does anyone have another idea?

Comment: the only idea: create minimal working code with your problem so others could run it and see problem.